# Close a page within a FRAME in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, window, frame

I have a window and a `Frame` whithin it. In that `Frame`, I open many pages which I would like to close by clicking on "Close" button I have created.

I have searched but it seems like no one knows how to do that.

Could anyone help me with that issue?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank page and just navigate to that when you close the page.

Comment: No way, there should be a "Right Way" to do that, but thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Create the following constructor in your page class to keep the reference:

```
class YourPageClass
{
public YourPageClass(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    main = mainWindow;
}
private MainWindow main;


}
```

Then, create this instance with passing main Window object:

```
 var page = new YourPageClass(this);
```

By doing that, you can get the main Window object. So now, you can close your Page object as follows:

```
    if (main != null)
        {
            main.ProjectorFrame.Content = "";
        }
```

I hope this help you